# Error in uploading large size of files : EXC E:java.io.IOException: Posted content length of 12000169 exceeds limit of 1048576

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, multipart

I got this error when I try to upload 11.4 MB text file.

```
EXC E:java.io.IOException: Posted content length of 12000169 exceeds limit of 1048576
```

Here's my *upload.jsp*

```
  <html>
  <body >
   <form action="read.jsp" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" >
  <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/master.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/nav.css" />
  </head>
  <p>


  <h1>UPLOAD</h1><br>
  </p>
   <p>
  <h3>          Please specify a file:</h3><br>
            <input type="file" name="file" size="40">
  </p>
  <div>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Here's my *read.jsp*

```
 <html>  
 <head>  
 <title>display</title>  
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
 <%@page import="java.io.*" %>  
 <%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>

  </head>  
 <body >
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/master.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/nav.css" />
  <p>


  <h1>      read text file</h1><br>
  </p>
  <%  

  String path="/apps/text/";
  String fileName="";
  String PhoneModel = GetPhoneModel();

   File a1=null;
   try{
  MultipartRequest multi=new MultipartRequest(request, path);
  a1=multi.getFile("file");
   } catch (Exception e){out.print("EXC E:"+e);}

  try{

  BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a1));  
      String fileData = "";  
  String crossSell="";

      while((fileData = is.readLine()) != null)  
        {
                out.println(fileData
        }

       }catch(Exception e){}

      %>  

     <p>
     <h1>Process Completed!</h1><br>
     </p>

    </body>  
   </html>
```

How can I remove the maximum limit of content length so that I can upload large files?

Answer (score 2):

MultipartRequest has a default max size of 1048576. you can change this when calling the constructor.

```
MultipartRequest multi=new MultipartRequest(request, path, newSize);
```